# Dplyr: group_by and convert multiple columns to a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question about how to convert multiple columns to a vector. I have the following dataset that I would like to group them by their condition and take all the position count into one vector. I know I can use as.vector() to convert them individually but I wonder if there is a dplyr way. Thank you!

```
test -> structure(list(gene_id = c("gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", 
"gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", 
"gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", 
"gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0", "gene0"), codon_index = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), position_1_count = c(2L, 7L, 8L, 
0L, 2L, 22L, 19L, 15L, 134L, 1L, 127L, 30L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 65L, 
234L, 1L, 3L, 57L, 0L, 4L, 16L), position_2_count = c(0L, 5L, 
5L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 13L, 134L, 0L, 36L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 150L, 
7L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 0L, 6L, 1L), position_3_count = c(0L, 2L, 1L, 
0L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 32L, 43L, 3L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 105L, 1L, 
0L, 14L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 1L), condition = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("c", "cup", "n", "nup", "p", 
"pup", "min", "rich"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), .Names = c("gene_id", 
"codon_index", "position_1_count", "position_2_count", "position_3_count", 
"condition"))

> head(a)
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  gene_id codon_index position_1_count position_2_count position_3_count condition
    <chr>       <int>            <int>            <int>            <int>    <fctr>
1   gene0           1                2                0                0         c
2   gene0           2                7                5                2         c
3   gene0           3                8                5                1         c
4   gene0           1                0                0                0       min
5   gene0           2                2                3                4       min
6   gene0           3               22                2                0       min
```

How can we convert this dataset to (I didn't add the column names here)

```
2 0 0 7 5 2 8 5 1 c
0 0 0 2 3 4 22 2 0 min
```

Comment: I would go with `library(data.table) ; setDT(test)[, paste(c(t(.SD)), collapse = " "), .SDcols = position_1_count:position_3_count, by = condition]` as it seems like `group_by` can't handle this for some reason

Comment: @DavidArenburg I provided a not so elegant way with `group_by()`

Comment: @StevenBeaupré Yeah, I saw. Still can't understand why just `test %>% group_by(condition) %>% select(position_1_count:condition) %>% summarise(res = paste(c(t(.[,-4])), collapse = " "))` wouldn't work

Comment: @DavidArenburg It would work with `do()`: `test %>% group_by(condition) %>% select(position_1_count:condition) %>% do(res = c(t(.[,-4])))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
library(purrr)

test %>%
  slice_rows("condition") %>%
  by_slice(function(x) unlist(x[-(1:2)]), .to = "vec")
```

Which gives:

```
#  condition                                vec
#1         c          2, 7, 8, 0, 5, 5, 0, 2, 1
#2       cup   4, 65, 234, 1, 150, 7, 4, 105, 1
#3         n 19, 15, 134, 3, 13, 134, 3, 32, 43
#4       nup        1, 3, 57, 0, 7, 7, 0, 14, 5
#5         p      1, 127, 30, 0, 36, 5, 3, 9, 1
#6       pup         0, 4, 16, 0, 6, 1, 0, 6, 1
#7       min         0, 2, 22, 0, 3, 2, 0, 4, 0
#8      rich          0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

---

As per mentioned in the comments by @advance, if you want the result rowwise:

```
test %>% 
  slice_rows("condition") %>% 
  by_slice(function(x) as.vector(t(x[-(1:2)])), .to = "vec")

#  condition                                vec
#1         c          2, 0, 0, 7, 5, 2, 8, 5, 1
#2       cup   4, 1, 4, 65, 150, 105, 234, 7, 1
#3         n 19, 3, 3, 15, 13, 32, 134, 134, 43
#4       nup        1, 0, 0, 3, 7, 14, 57, 7, 5
#5         p      1, 0, 3, 127, 36, 9, 30, 5, 1
#6       pup         0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 6, 16, 1, 1
#7       min         0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 22, 2, 0
#8      rich          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

---

Or adapting @DavidArenburg's comment using `do()` instead of `summarise()`:

```
test %>% 
  group_by(condition) %>% 
  select(position_1_count:condition) %>%
  do(res = c(t(.[,-4])))
```

Which gives:

```
#  condition                                res
#1         c          2, 0, 0, 7, 5, 2, 8, 5, 1
#2       cup   4, 1, 4, 65, 150, 105, 234, 7, 1
#3         n 19, 3, 3, 15, 13, 32, 134, 134, 43
#4       nup        1, 0, 0, 3, 7, 14, 57, 7, 5
#5         p      1, 0, 3, 127, 36, 9, 30, 5, 1
#6       pup         0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 6, 16, 1, 1
#7       min         0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 4, 22, 2, 0
#8      rich          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0
```

Comment: The row-wise is exactly what I want, but computationally takes too long to process. The format of list as in the first one using purrr is actually really nice. However, it doesn't seem like purrr can take a sliced matrix and convert it to a vector. I tried test %>%
  slice_rows("condition") %>%
  by_slice(function(x) unlist(x[-(1:2)]), .to = "vec")

Comment: test %>%
  slice_rows("condition") %>%
  by_slice(function(x) as.vector(t(x[-(1:2)])), .to = "vec")

Comment: @advance That's the way to go, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Am I correct that what you want is a separate vector for all of the counts for each condition? If so, a mix of `dplyr` and `tidyr` should do it. First, I `gather` to put all of the counts in a single column. Then, `split` to separate by the condition, then use `lapply` to generate a list, containing a separate vector for each condition:

```
a %>%
  gather(Location, Count, starts_with("position")) %>%
  split(.$condition) %>%
  lapply(function(x){x$Count})
```

gives:

```
$c
[1] 2 7 8 0 5 5 0 2 1

$cup
[1]   4  65 234   1 150   7   4 105   1

$n
[1]  19  15 134   3  13 134   3  32  43

$nup
[1]  1  3 57  0  7  7  0 14  5

$p
[1]   1 127  30   0  36   5   3   9   1

$pup
[1]  0  4 16  0  6  1  0  6  1

$min
[1]  0  2 22  0  3  2  0  4  0

$rich
[1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If the order matters (and is wrong above) you should be able to sort before splitting, e.g. by adding `arrange(codon_index)` after `gather`

Comment: That doesn't look like the desired output though. They want it rowise, not colwise.

Comment: Good catch on the order @DavidArenburg . Adding `arrange` would allow any desired sort. Edited now.

Comment: Don't think `arrange` has anything to do here.

Comment: Arrange will sort the columns by whatever you give it. It is not a general solution to the row-wise vs. column-wise problem, but in this case, because the codon_index is sorted in the original data, it works. However, the OP gives no indication that the order itself matters. If it does, they are likely better off stopping after the `gather` step (or maybe `split`) and leaving the location identifying information with the values.

Comment: Adding arrange seems to be working. Other than saving it as list, can we save the output as a data frame with condition in one column and count in another one as a list? Like the purrr example above?

Answer (score 1):

After taking Peterson's idea, I think this code works the best:

```
test %>% gather(Location, Count, starts_with("position"))  %>% arrange(codon_index)  %>% group_by(condition) %>% do(count = as.vector(t(.$Count)))
```

The result will look like this

```
> ans = test %>% gather(Location, Count, starts_with("position"))  %>% arrange(codon_index)  %>% group_by(condition) %>% do(count = as.vector(t(.$Count)))

    # A tibble: 8 × 2
      condition     count
    *    <fctr>    <list>
    1         c <int [9]>
    2       cup <int [9]>
    3         n <int [9]>
    4       nup <int [9]>
    5         p <int [9]>
    6       pup <int [9]>
    7       min <int [9]>
    8      rich <int [9]>
> ans$count[[1]]
[1] 2 0 0 7 5 2 8 5 1
```

Thanks a lot for everyone's help!